# how to remove the loop attribute in a html 5 video tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, video

i have a page that uses videos in background and i have it set to loop on the main page.

i want to use JQuery to change the file and the attributes;

My code is

```
$("#garden").mouseover(function() {
    var videoFile = 'gardenlift.webm';
    $('#backgroundv video').attr({
        src: videoFile,
        loop: 'false'
    });
```

Its Not working! the second video still play in loop. How can i use jquery to remove the loop attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.prop('loop', false)` - the attribute is not a boolean attribute but its *existence* causes looping to be enabled.

`src` is most likely a property, too, so you can safely replace `attr` with `prop` in your code.

Comment: how would you integrate it with the attribute change? im trying to just stop the loop and its not working

Comment: if i change attr by prop nothing happen

Comment: chrome is telling me that the object has no method prop

Comment: Sounds like you are using an ancient jQuery version. I think `.prop()` was added in 1.5 or 1.6.

Comment: Dang! Thank you! That was it Thanks